# How to fix A value of type 'AuthResult' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'FirebaseUser'

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I tried to change form firebaseuser to authresults

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
abstract class AuthImplementaion {

}
class Auth implements AuthImplementaion {
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  Future<String> SignIn(String _email, String _password) async{
    FirebaseUser user = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, password: _password);
    return user.uid;
  }
}
```

message: A value of type "AuthResult" can't be assigned to a variable of type "FirebaseUser".Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to "FirebaseUser"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`_firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, password: _password)` returns a `AuthResult` like it's mentioned in your error message. But the `AuthResult` provides a `user` that is a `FirebaseUser`.

So, you have to also call `.user`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
abstract class AuthImplementaion {

}
class Auth implements AuthImplementaion {
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  Future<String> SignIn(String _email, String _password) async{
    FirebaseUser user = (await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, password: _password)).user;
    return user.uid;
  }
}
```

Comment: '
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  Future<String> SignIn(String _email, String _password) async{
    FirebaseUser user = (await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, password: _password)) as FirebaseUser;
    return user.uid;
  }
  Future<String> SignUp(String _email, String _password) async{
    FirebaseUser user = (await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, password: _password)) as FirebaseUser;
    return user.uid;
  }' what happen if i remove _ from email and password

Comment: You can write another question, if it is not related to the problem of this question of yours. But if you want ask here and I tell you if it's need to be asked as a new question.

Comment: I want to edit the same code and just remove _ from email and password

Comment: So you want to add a method to delete a user from your firebase auth?

Comment: no, I will ask another question hope I would get help there. thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Assign this to a AuthResult variable and that in turn contains the user and that user contains the uid.

AuthResult authresult already contains the user with uid.
Instead of returning user.uid
return authResult.user.uid;

```
class Auth implements AuthImplementaion {
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  Future<String> SignIn(String _email, String _password) async{
    AuthResult authResult = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, password: _password);
    return authResult.user.uid;
  }
}
```